# unable to sign the unsigned APK

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, keystore

I'm trying to sign the unsigned APK. I followed [this link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html).

My steps:

1. `$ cordova build --release android` (success)
2. `$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name - keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` (success)
3. `$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name` (got problem)

The problem is:

> jarsigner: unable to open jar file: HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk

Then i followed [this link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-publishing/3762).

1. `$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -my-release-key.keystore F:\mobile\moto\whatever_the_path_is_to_your_apk_file\HelloCordova-release-unsigned.apk alias_name` (got problem)

the problem is:

> Illegal option: -my-release-key.keystore

Can anyone help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to remove the `-` in front of the `keystore`file and add the flag `-keystore`:

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore F:\mobile\moto\whatever_the_path_is_to_your_apk_file\HelloCordova-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

Generally I use these commands to generate a `release build apk` that I will publish in the Google Play Store:

```
cd ~/Projects/myappname/
cordova build android --release
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore certificates/myappname-cert.keystore -storepass myappname -keypass myappname platforms/android/ant-build/CordovaApp-release-unsigned.apk myappname
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs platforms/android/ant-build/CordovaApp-release-unsigned.apk
~/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/21.1.2/zipalign -v 4 platforms/android/ant-build/CordovaApp-release-unsigned.apk releases/android/myappname1.0.0.apk
```

Note that I created the dir. `certificates` with the .keystore certificate, and the dir. `releases/android` where I save all signed apk releases.

To generate a new `keystore` file with a new `password`:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore certificates/my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Comment: when i use this by removing the `-`  = `$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 my-release-key.keystore F:\mobile\moto\whatever_the_path_is_to_your_apk_file\HelloCordova-release-unsigned.apk alias_name` it telling me `the only one alias can be specified`

Comment: Then i tried this `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore -storepass try -keypass try C:\Users\Users\desktop\try\platform\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk try` it telling me `jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: keystore was tempered with, or password was incorrect`

Comment: I updated my answer adding the command to generate a new one keystore file with a new password.

Comment: Before this I'm using this `c:\Users\Users\desktop\try\platform\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk` then I changed into `platform\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk` just like you did. Then its working thanks for advanced :)

Answer (score 6):

**Steps to sign Corodva apk using keytool, jarsigner and zipalign are:**

### 1. Generate keystore for your app using keytool:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore android.keystore -alias android_app -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

### 2. Next create a certificate into a pkcs12 keystore format with keytool

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore android.keystore -destkeystore android.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12
```

It will create two files in Project_root_dir as **android.keystore (with pkcs12)** and **android.keystore.old (without pkcs12)**

### 3. Sign apk with jarsigner:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore android.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk android_app
```

> **First time you'll get below error as:**
>
> jarsigner: unable to open jar file: app-release-unsigned.apk

Then you just need to move .apk file from

> /Project_root_dir/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release unsigned.apk
>
> in to **Project_root_dir/**

Then again run the **jarsigner** command above, it will sign apk successfully.

### 4. Finally verify apk:

```
zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk app-release.apk
```

Your apk is signed successfully, you can publish it in play store.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

follow what @manzapanza have wrote, I also had to download zipalign from http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34706306/zipalign
move zipalign into Android `mv /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Downloads/zipalign /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk/tools` Give the execute permissions:

`chmod 777 /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk/tools/zipalign` Do the command jarsigner:  `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore yourkeystore.jks app-release-unsigned.apk aliayourkeystore`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this path and please write your keystore name as well as your alias name:-

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore salonify-release-key.keystore platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk salonify

Answer (score 0):

Just use absolute path instead of relative path as:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myApp.keystore E:\myApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk myApp
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run all the commands in the projects root directory, and the important thing, **you should move your apk file** after running `$ cordova build --release android` from `AwesomeProject\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release` to the project root directory.